# Organize timestamps into durations by status

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm working on a simple time tracking application and trying to figure out, what the most efficient way to organize the routine time bookings into  durations would be. 
I have a list of Objekts of my Timestamp class, like this:

```
public class Timestamp {
    int status;
    Date date;
}
```

The status translates to  this:

```
private static final int OUT = 0;
private static final int IN = 1;
private static final int BREAK = 2;
```

A duration is calculated from a timestamp with status 1 to one with Status 0 or 2.
My consideration is to order my list by date and then remove all useless timestamps, meaning all timestamps with with duplicate status. Any thoughts?

**Update:**

Trying to make clearer, what I mean...first I will describe the sequence of events in my application:
1. The user clocks in/out/for break.
2. An entry in my Database is created. The table where the entry is created has, among others, a column for the datetime when the user clocked in/out and a column "status". In the "status" column I store whether the user clocked in, starts his break or clocked out with a numeric value, in this example 0 for out, 1 for in and 2 for break.
3. Now my application should calculate the time, when the user worked and his break time for every day. To keep things simple, working time is calculated from first "clock in" of the day to next "clock out" or from "clock in" to "break". The break time is calculated from first "break" to next "clock in".
4. The result would then be saved in a different table, where I save the working duration and break duration by day.

As I already wrote, my take on would be:
- Get all data from table.
- Create an instance of my Timestamp class for every row and put them in a list.
- Remove all entries, that I don't use for my calculation, e.g. a duplicate "clock in" between a "clock in"-Timestamp and a "clock out"-Timestamp.
- Iterate through the list, find related Timestamps, remove them from the list and create a duration.
- sum up all durations until the whole day is processed.
- chache that day in another list, until all data is processed.
- insert chached durations data into corresponding table.

As you might imagine, the amount of data can grow quite huge, so I'm looking for a fast and efficient way to achive my goal. Hope this clarifies some things.

Comment: If all the timestamps refer to the same thing (operation, system, whatever) then it sounds reasonable. Any problems with that?

Comment: Consider making `Timestamp`s mutually comparable (i.e., `Timestamp implements Comparable<Timestamp>`) so you can use them with ordered collections and sort methods and such-like that work with `Comparable`s.

Comment: Please, update your question and provide more details. It is not clear, what input parameters you have and what you are waiting for as a result.

Comment: @Dmitrii I updated my question, hope this clarifies some things.